# Can a Bitcoin server have a .onion ToR address?

Tags: tor, privacy

Is it possible for a Bitcoin server to have a [.onion ToR address](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11727/396)?

If so, are there any in existence today?

(Note: this is an alternative to hiding addresses via the [Azure Service Bus](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4810/1878))

Comment: Although I accepted Pieter's answer, I'm still interested in finding .onion addresses that are available.  Please them as an answer if you know of any.

Comment: Note: "Bitcoin Server" is generally referred to as a Bitcoin Node or Full Node. (nitpicking, just to clarify)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since version 0.7 this is possible with the reference client.

See the documentation about tor: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md

EDIT: also see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fallback_Nodes#Tor_nodes for a list of published onion nodes. The explanation on that site should be updated to reflected the built-in support for onion addresses since 0.7.0, though.

Comment: There is a current setup guide for Bitcoin Core and Tor available on Bitcoin.SE [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70069/how-can-i-setup-bitcoin-to-be-anonymous-with-tor).